# Setting up user_ctx field on CouchDB Replicator

Tags: couchdb, database-replication

```
"user_ctx": {
       "name": "adminuser",
       "role": "[\"_admin\"]"
   },
   "_replication_state": "error",
   "_replication_state_time": "2011-08-30T15:09:03+00:00",
   "_replication_id": "08fd9d6dcc5a0882fc9fd0d971b05938"
}
```

For some reason, I can't get my replicator to work.  The log continues to show "unauthorized to access database", referring to my localhost.  I know I need to have user_ctx set, but for some reason it just doesn't like to work.  I copied the info out of my source.  I even created new admin users to try and fix the problem, none worked.  Do I need to specify more roles for the user?

The other has a good resource https://gist.github.com/832610, but the user_ctx he set's in the example isn't the admin user, the appear to just be random roles.

Anyone have any experience with the CouchDB replicating to the localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what I did thanks to the CouchDB Apache Mailing Lists. Should have had "roles" instead of "role".

Answer (score 0):

If you create the document as the server admin, then you do not need this field. I think omitting it completely will work.

If you create the document as a normal user, then it should match your name and roles which you can get by querying `/_session`. In fact, I think you can copy the `userCtx` field from the session response directly into the `user_ctx` field of the replication document.